# Are these two vb methods identical in function?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub ChangeCursor(ByVal target As FrameworkElement, ByVal cursor As Cursor)
    target.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        New DispatcherOperationCallback( _
            Function()
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = cursor
                Return Nothing
            End Function),
        Nothing)
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub ChangeCursor(ByVal target As FrameworkElement, ByRef cursor As Cursor)

    target.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        New DispatcherOperationCallback( _
            Function(cursor1 as Cursor)
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = cursor1
                Return Nothing
            End Function),
        cursor)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd snippet is probably cheaper.  The lambda doesn't have to capture the value of the cursor argument.  They are otherwise functionally the same.  Try not to sweat the small stuff.

Answer (score 0):

By "in function" do you mean "in terms of what they *do*"? If so then I'd have to say yes.